# Tensorflow 2.13.0 No module named 'tensorflow.keras' Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I ran into the issue above when coding in spyder through anaconda. Pretty sure the issue popped up when i opened a new file in an environment where i already made and saved a tf keras model and I tried to fetch it in that new file.

After that I tried everything I can think of including factory reseting my machine and reinstalling everything from scratch, the only thing left was some stuff from Onedrive. I've tried pip and conda installs, made sure the versions were the same, updated everything, etc. No use.
What I have found however is that tensorflow.python.keras works, however many things like layers.Dense, BatchNormalization, Dropout, etc. all don't work so I don't know what to do.
current versions:

```
tensorflow                    2.12.0
keras                         2.12.0
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of a new version of `Tensorflow`. 
Now `Keras` is in `Tensorflow` and you need to import as `tensorflow.keras`. 

Also `Windows` doesn't support `Tensorflow` GPU on `Windows` anymore as stated here:
[Install TensorFlow with pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) 
You need to install as;

```
pip install tensorflow-cpu
```

on `Windows`.

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work, I have used pip and conda to install several versions on many new environments and it simply won't work as it did when I installed it for the first time and as the documentation states.

Comment: "install several versions" my environment is messed up after doing this. It says my tensorflow doesn't even have __version__ anymore. Others say if this is the case then we need to recreate the environment.