# I cannot import tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have used pip to install tensorflow with no errors, yet when my python scripts tries to import tensorflow I get **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'**

What am I missing?

I expect tensorflow to load.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Comment: you forgot to install it first

Comment: The most common cause of this is that you are using an IDE (like VSCode or Jupyter) that has its own installation of Python, and you did your `pip install` in a different one.

Comment: There are lots of existing Q&As about "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'" ... that cover lots of reasons why that can happen.  Try this Google search: `modulenotfounderror no module named 'tensorflow' site:stackoverflow.com` and see if any of the questions **and answers** match your situation.

Comment: *"What am I missing?"* - In short ... there are many possible things you could be missing.

Comment: This question appears to be a duplication of [Tensorflow 2.13.0 No module named 'tensorflow.keras' Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76880107/13664137)

Answer (score 1):

You first need to install tensorflow before using it. If you have python installed on your device, type in the cmd :

```
python -m pip install tensorflow
```

If you get the error `python is not recognized as an internal command ...`, then type

```
cd [path to your python.exe]
```

and retry the first command.

Answer (score -1):

windows doesnt support tensorflow gpu on windows anymore as steted here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native. You need to install as `pip install tensorflow-cpu` on windows.(If you use windows)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.